# How do I change a variable in one java class from another, then access that changed variable from a third java class?

Tags: java

So say I have 3 java classes, A, B, and C. Class A has an int variable named num that equals 3. I want to be able to change num from class B to another number (for example, 45), then access that variable from class C so that it equals 45. How would I do this?

```
//First Class
public class A
{
    public int num;

    public A() {
        num = 3;
    }

    public void setNum(int newNum) {
        num = newNum;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}

//Second Class
public class B
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        C c = new C();

        System.out.println(a.getNum());

        a.setNum(45);

        System.out.println(a.getNum());

        c.printStuff();
    }
}

//Third Class
public class C
{
    public void printStuff() {
        A a = new A();

        System.out.println(a.getNum());
    }
}
```

The first two print statements output the expected 3 and 45, but the print statement in the C class still outputs a 3, even though I changed num's value to 45 in class B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you cann't get the result you want, is that you have created a new instance of class `A` in class `C`, and it has its own value, which is `3`. Changing the value of the instance of class `A` which is defined in class `B` will not effect this new instance.

Note that you called the `new` method on class `A` two times so you have two seperate instances.

You can try this code to get the result you want:

```
//First Class
class A
{
    public int num;

public A() {
    num = 3;
}

public void setNum(int newNum) {
    num = newNum;
}

public int getNum() {
    return num;
}
}

//Second Class
public class B
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    C c = new C();

    System.out.println(a.getNum());

    a.setNum(45);

    System.out.println(a.getNum());

    c.printStuff(a);
}
}

//Third Class
class C
{
public void printStuff(A a) {
    //A a = new A();

    System.out.println(a.getNum());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats happens because in `C` `class` you are creating a new instance of `A` again. So the value would be `3`. You can change your constructor and call it like this,

```
public A(int value) {
    num = value;
}

new Post(45);
```

By this when you create a instance you can assign a value to num as you wish from any `class`.